# Site Collection Permissions

Tags: permissions, access

I have to add an AD group to a specific site collection, but need to give them permissions to be able to only view all list, libraries, video's, and to be able to download excel files, powerpoints, etc...?

Any Idea's?

Comment: The only read access is: wall approvers - Read... Restricted Readers - limited access read...  Visitors - Limited Read

Comment: You can also add the AD group to have READ access. Just go to Site Permissions -> Grant Permissions -> Add the AD Account in "Select Users" -> Click the Grant users permission directly in "Grant Permissions", and Select Read -> Press OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add that group to a Site Collection Readers group in SharePoint permissions.

```
Site Actions -> Site Permissions
```

This will list the permissions for the site. You can add that group under the "Site Readers" and they can view and download the files they need to. Just click on that group and then go to `New -> Add Users -> type the AD Group -> Press OK.`

Every user in that AD Group will be able to read the contents of that site.